# Show that there exists a filter $\mathcal G$ on $X$ such that $\mathcal F \subseteq \mathcal G$ and $\mathcal G$ converges to $c$.

Tags: general-topology, filters

I have the following problem:

> Let $\left( {X,\tau } \right)$ be a topological space, $\mathcal F$ a filter on $X$ and $ c \in X$ a cluster point of $\mathcal F$. Show that there exists a filter $\mathcal G$ on $X$ such that $\mathcal F  \subseteq \mathcal G$ and $\mathcal G$ converges to $c$.

Is it sufficient to say that:

Given the above, then $\mathcal G$ has $c$ as cluster point; then we can construct a filter 
$$\mathcal C = \left\{ {U \cap G\;|\;U \in {\mathcal{N}_c}{\text{ and }}G \in \mathcal{G}} \right\}$$ for a filter $\mathcal{F}$, where ${\mathcal{N}_c}$ is the neighborhood of $c$. This also shows that $\mathcal{F}$ is finer than $\mathcal{G}$, meaning $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{G}$, and $\mathcal G$ converges to $c$.

Please correct me if this is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. By [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3612811/4280), because we're in the second case where $$\forall U \in \mathcal{N}_c: \forall F \in \mathcal{F}: U \cap F \neq \emptyset$$

because $c$ is a cluster point of $\mathcal{F}$, we know $\mathcal{G} = \{U \cap F \mid U \in \mathcal{N}_c, F \in \mathcal{F}\}$ is indeed a filter on $X$.

And indeed $\mathcal{N}_c \subseteq \mathcal{G}$ (take $F=X$ e.g.), so $\mathcal{G}\to c$ and $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{G}$ (pick $U=X$) so $\mathcal{G}$ is as required.

Comment: The OP's $\mathcal C$ would be a filter if $\mathcal N_c$ were the neighborhood filter of $c$ (rather than just the set of *open* neighborhoods of $c$). That might or might not be what the OP intended to write instead of "$\mathcal N_c$ is the neighborhood of $c$" (which doesn't really make sense).

Comment: @AndreasBlass Have you a better example of $\{A \cap B: A \in \mathcal{F}, B \in \mathcal{G}\}$ not being a filter, while all these sets are non-empty, with $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ filters?

Comment: No, I think those intersections will always form a filter when $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ are filters. The only issue is closure under supersets. With notation as in your comment, suppose $C\supseteq A\cap B$. Then $C\cup A\in\mathcal F$ and $C\cup B\in\mathcal G$ and their intersection is $(C\cup A)\cap(C\cup B)=C\cup(A\cap B)=C$.

Comment: Should the filter base rather be $\mathcal C = \left\{ {U \cap G\;|\;U \in {\mathcal{N}_c}{\text{ and }}F \in \mathcal{F}} \right\}$?

Comment: @pabhp by the other exercise and the previous comments by Andreas, we see the intersections form not just a filterbase but a proper filter. See my edited answer.