# Prove that $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{P}\left( X \right)$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a set, $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ filters on $X$. Consider $\mathcal{H} = \left\{ {F \cap G\;|\;F \in \mathcal{F},G \in \mathcal{G}} \right\}$. Prove that $\mathcal{H}$ is a filter on $X$ or $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{P}\left( X \right)$

I have no problem in proving that $\mathcal{H}$ is a filter on $X$, also I know $\mathcal{H} \subseteq \mathcal{P}\left( X \right)$, but how does one show that $\mathcal{P}\left( X \right) \subseteq \mathcal{H}$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this statement. Is $\mathcal{P}(X)$ the power set? The power set is a filter as well, isn't it? So this "or" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It is the power set yes. This is a homework question, could the "or $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{P}\left( X \right)$" be an error?

Comment: @freakish  In topology filters do not contain the empty set.  In order theory perhaps they might depending what is being considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that *filter* here means *proper filter*, since $\mathscr{H}$ is always a filter in the sense that it is closed under taking finite intersections and supersets. (This is in fact pretty common usage.) Since $\mathscr{H}$ **is** closed under taking finite intersections and supersets, the only way in which it can fail to be a (proper) filter is by containing the empty set. But if $\varnothing\in\mathscr{H}$, then every subset of $X$ is in $\mathscr{H}$, since every subset of $X$ contains $\varnothing$. Thus, $\wp(X)\subseteq\mathscr{H}\subseteq\wp(X)$, and $\mathscr{H}=\wp(X)$.

Answer (score 2):

First note that $\mathcal{H}$ is closed under intersections and supersets:

The former is obvious as $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are closed under intersections and $(F_1 \cap G_1) \cap (F_2 \cap G_2) = (F_1 \cap F_2) \cap (G_1 \cap G_2)$, and for the latter, suppose that $F \cap G \subseteq C \subseteq X$, where $F \in \mathcal{F}$ and $G \in \mathcal{G}$, then $F \cup C \in \mathcal{F}$ as $F \subseteq F \cup C$ and also $G \cup C \in \mathcal{G}$. But then $(F \cup C) \cap (G \cup C) = C \cup (F \cap G) = C \in \mathcal{H}$.

There are two cases:

1. There is some $F_0 \in \mathcal{F}$ and some $G_0 \in \mathcal{G}$ such that $F_0 \cap G_0 = \emptyset$. In that case, $\emptyset \in \mathcal{H}$ and as all subsets of $X$ are supersets of $\emptyset$, $\mathcal{H} = \mathscr{P}(X)$.
2. For all $F \in \mathcal{F}$ and all $G \in \mathcal{G}$, $F \cap G \neq \emptyset$. This means, together with the first paragraph, that $\mathcal{H}$ is a (proper) filter on $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Your claim that H is a filter is wrong.
Here is an example why.

F = { A subset R : 0 in A } 
and
G = { A subset R : $\pi$ in A }
are principle ultrafilters for R.
H = { A $\cap$ B : A in F, B in G } = P(R).
H is not a filter.  Why?

The problem is asking to show H is either a filter
OR H = P(R).

Comment: Therefore if the empty set is not in $\mathcal{H}$ it would be a filter. If the empty set is indeed in $\mathcal{H}$, how does one prove that $\mathcal{P}\left( X \right) = \mathcal{H}$?

Comment: Because a filter F is an upper set,  for all A in F, B subset X, B in F.